# PHP Session variable checking is not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my issue I'm a bigger in PHP I have done a login page and it is working perfectly in my local machine But after uploading to Server its not working.

Session is created but redirection is not happening.

here is my code and any help is really appreciated.

```
if( isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      include 'connection.php';
      $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '$username' AND password = sha1('$password') AND status = '1'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      $result = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
      $userId = '';
      if( $result) {
        $userId = $result['id'];
        $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;
        if( $userId == 1) {
          header("location:map.php");
        } else if( $userId == 2){
          header("location:admin/map-settings.php");
        } else {
          echo "<li class='loginError'>There is an Error in Login Please Contact Administrator</li>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "<li class='loginError'>Invalid Username or Password</li>";
      }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the thing? Where does it go wrong? What is the expected result. What is the result?

Comment: Also SQL injection galore

Comment: did you happen to start your session? session_start()?

Comment: **1-** did you change the connection.php accordingly? **2-** your tables may differ between local and server did you check? **3-** did you upload yourRedirect.phps in the right location to your server? What exactly $result is returning? What is the result of your $userId after `$userId = $result['id'];` **-->** give us more information :(

Answer (score 0):

make sure to `print_r($_SESSION)`

If it did not give empty array, then your session is set.

now make sure nothing in your code started output before you set the "Location" header.
and you could use this to redirect your page

```
if (!headers_sent())
             $filename="map.php";
             header('Location: '.$filename);
        else {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'window.location.href="'.$filename.'";';
                echo '</script>';
                echo '<noscript>';
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$filename.'" />';
                echo '</noscript>';
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply
the session variable are set after submitting correct username and password I can manually type url to map.php its working properly 
The only problem is automatic redirection after entering correct uname and password. 

and it is perfectly  working in my local machine

Comment: just try my given code for redirection, if all things are ok, then it will sure redirect your page to map.php...